# How to convert IDN to ASCII?

Tags: c#, .net, idn

What is the best way to convert an [internationalized domain name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) to its ASCII-form?

I want to convert **`Bücher.ch`** into **`xn--bcher-kva.ch`** by using some sort of (free) .net code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [GNU IDN Library - Libidn](http://www.gnu.org/software/libidn/). The introduction says that C# libraries are available.

Comment: -1 for suggesting a 3rd party library when .NET itself is capable of this.

Comment: @Venemo The .NET library does not support all chars. [link](http://manage.resellerclub.com/kb/answer/1740) for example: **ß** is not supported.

Answer (score 37):

```
using System.Globalization;
...
IdnMapping idn = new IdnMapping();
MessageBox.Show(idn.GetAscii("www.kraków.pl"));
```

Answer (score 6):

To Get the other way around from xn--bcher-kva.ch domain to Bücher.ch

```
using System.Globalization;
...
IdnMapping idn = new IdnMapping();
MessageBox.Show(idn.GetUnicode("xn--bcher-kva.ch"));
```

You will get www.kraków.pl as result.
Because i came here to look for this :) hope it is helpful for others as well :)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx1d9321%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)