# Convert Unicode to ASCII in URL (domain and parameters)

Tags: c#, .net, url, idn

I have an Url, for example, `http://кц.рф/ru/registrators/` and want to convert it to `http://xn--j1ay.xn--p1ai/ru/registrators/` form.

```
new System.Globalization.IdnMapping().GetAscii(href) 
// result: xn--http://-jig2i.xn--/ru/registrators/-zdo8d
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(href)
// result: http://%d0%ba%d1%86.%d1%80%d1%84/ru/registrators/
```

More general problem is to normalize urls like: `http://кц.рф/ru/registrators/q?рф=세요`

Is there a simpler way to do this rather than:

1. Get domain part
2. If there are any Unicode symbols, process domain part using `IdnMapping().GetAscii`
3. Process query part using `Uri.EscapeUriString()`

Partially related question [how-to-convert-idn-to-ascii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852274/how-to-convert-idn-to-ascii)